# Does there exist constant overhead reduction between common cryptographic primitives?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, reductions, cryptography

I have proved that there exist such reduction between error-correcting codes and exposure resilient functions, which is because that the *transpose* of a generator matrix for a ERC mapping $\mathbb{F}_2^m$ to $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ with distance $d$ *is* an $l$-ERF where $l=n-d+1$. Does there exist constant-multiplicative-overhead reductions between other cryptographic primitives, for example, between encryption and error-correcting code? The above question is stated under the context of circuit complexity.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it would qualify as a *reduction* in your terms per se, but there is certainly a connection between [universal hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing) and error-correcting codes. Universal hashes are often used in cryptography to build message authenticators, such as [Poly1305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305) and [GHASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode#Mathematical_basis).

A theorem by Bierbrauer, et al. in *"On Families of Hash Functions via Geometric Codes and Concatenation"* states, informally, that if certain codes exist that certain universal hashes exist, and vice versa.

I'd suggest *"On the Connections Between Universal Hashing, Combinatorial Designs and Error-Correcting Codes"* by Douglas R. Stinson for background and *"On the Minimum Number of Multiplications Necessary for Universal Hash Functions"* by Mridul Nandi for a concrete example, if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you. I will refer to these papers for details.